# css positioning divs in a browser

Tags: css, html

What would be the best way to position divs in any browser, so I have the following setup:

div all (that includes all the following divs and has a width of 800 px and centers in the middle of the page)

div content (that centers within div all)

div menu left (within div all) and a li with my menu items and fixed distance of 10 px from left border of div all)

div menu right (within div all) and same as div menu left but 10 py from right side

So

div all (div content , div menu left, div menu right)

And if I resize the browser it follows until the div all size (800px) is reached. You call this liquid I guess.

Comment: can you explain better what the div content wish to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called liquid layout, here is an article that covers it
http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/

Answer (score 0):

Experiment use % not px; See?

Now try to use media-screen:

```
<pre>
@media screen and (max-width: 1099px) {
/*your css code for small resolution*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
/*your css code for big resolution*/

}
</pre>
```

look this: http://jsfiddle.net/Csje2/